# Why in matlab orth function much slower than qr?

Tags: algorithm, matlab, matrix

I'm orthogonalizing big matrices in matlab and I've noticed function orth being much slower than qr, for example:

```
>> a = randn(200000, 80);
tic; orth(a); toc;
Elapsed time is 2.472516 seconds.
>> tic; qr(a); toc;
Elapsed time is 0.610215 seconds.
```

What could cause such a big difference?

Comment: From sniffing the documentation, `orth` might be using an SVD versus `qr` using Gram--Schmidt (or some other cubic algorithm), but I'm not confident enough to post this as an answer.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat `orth` does use SVD, as can be seen in its code. `qr` is a built-in function, so your guess is yet to be confirmed

Comment: @DavidEisenstat so I will loose some orthogonality with qr because of rounding errors?

Comment: I wouldn't expect there to be a meaningful difference in output quality unless one vector is close to the span of the others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that `qr` is indeed the faster way to go.

Logically that means that it must have a disadvantage, otherwise Matlab would not continue to use this slower method.

The two things that you would mostly want to look out for:

- Memory requirement
- accuracy

Though it is possible that something else is the reason for implementing `orth` the way it is done now, my guess would be one of those.

---

Sidenote you may also want to check out this simple [Gram Schmidt](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-06-linear-algebra-spring-2010/related-resources/MIT18_06S10_gramschmidtmat.pdf) solution for comparison.

Comment: Another reason to keep `orth` the same is so that any old code that uses it continues to produce *exactly* the same results.

Comment: @horchler That is definitely a consideration, but it is probably not enough. If it was only left intact for backwards compatibility one would either expect a hint in the doc, or some kind of flag. ('fast', 'legacy'). -- I realize this entire answer is guesswork, but it remains my best guess.